# pgAdmin does not integrate shp2pgsql in menu

Tags: shp2pgsql

Recently I updated my pgAdmin to 4, and I still want to use PostGIS Shapefile Import/Export Manager. I did not find any method to make this happen and even if shp2pgsql-gui still works outside pgadmin, this does not appear on pgAdmin's menu.

Am I doing something wrong, or is it no available on this version?